# Fast and scalable IO passthrough

Tags: java, amazon-s3, nio, nonblocking, aws-sdk

## Original

I have a batch job that passes through the contents it downloads from various URLs to an S3 storage. I am currently using blocking IO and have reached a point where my job is <strike>IO bound</strike> blocking most of the time because of IO. So in order to speed up the whole process I was thinking about using non-blocking IO.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find utility code for passing through content from a set of channels to another set of channels. Since I read that writing correct non-blocking code is not exactly easy, I would prefer to use an existing utility/framework than to write that code myself.

The [TransferManager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) seems to be the only possible option for higher throughput when using the AWS SDK, but it only offers the usage of streams and seems to use IO threads in the background. Apparently there is no out of the box option for non-blocking uploads to S3.

What would you recommend? Right now I can only imagine the following solutions.

1. Stay with blocking IO and use my own IO thread pool
2. Use non-blocking IO to download the files to the local filesystem, then upload with TransferManager
3. Use non-blocking IO for pass through

Option 1 will obviously not scale and 2 will probably work for a while, but I would really like to keep my IOs on EBS low so I'd rather use 3.

To successfully implement option 3 I guess I would have to implement a lot myself so my final question is, whether you think it's worth it and if so, which tools I could use to make this work.

## Edit 1

Clarifying that by IO bound I actually meant that the job is mostly waiting for IO. Here you can see that my bandwidth is not really saturated, but I would like it to be if that is possible.
[image: Monitoring view]

Comment: What do you mean non blocking uploads? What io is bound? Disk reads? Writes? Network reads? Writes?

Answer (score 0):

If your job is I/O bound you've finished. You're bound by the speed of the network, not of your code. Using NIO won't make it any faster.

> Clarifying that by IO bound I actually meant that the job is mostly waiting for IO.

Yes, that's what 'I/O bound' means. Nothing has changed.

> Here you can see that my bandwidth is not really saturated, but I would like it to be if that is possible.

You could try using larger buffers, but as I said it seems to me that you've already finished.

Comment: My connection count currently is 2 which is why my bandwidth is not saturated. Currently one slow server will slow down my whole job, which is why I wanted to use non blocking IO. Also my reads seem to fail(HTTP 5xx) very often which I try to handle by waiting a bit.